# Attributes Ignored for <Input type="number" /> in Html 5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I had test it in chrome, opera and Microsoft edge but still attributes **except value and name** are ignored.

```
<input type="number" class="input-number" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" step="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" />
```

---

**In short, my increment and decrement button bypass the restriction** Here is the whole HTML code

```
<div class="quantity ml-auto">
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="input-number" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" step="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" />
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I am using Jquery also. If i remove this script than attributes work perfectly. Maybe there is a problem in this script.

```
<script>
    $('.input-number-increment').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
  $input.val(val + 1);

});

$('.input-number-decrement').click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).parents('.input-number-group').find('.input-number');
  var val = parseInt($input.val(),  10);
  $input.val(val - 1);

});


</script>
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? I'd guess your increment/decrement buttons can *bypass* the restrictions; if so, you need to rework your JS to handle that scenario.

Comment: Yeah i have tried it but could not find the way to do so. That's why i added a question here.

Comment: Your JS code does not check for attributes existence and just increments value and since you _can_ enter invalid value - no problem for JS

Comment: @AhmarAamir You need to check what the value will be when you increment/decrement, and check that against your restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got my answer. Here is the final code.

---

HTML Code

```
<div class="quantity ml-auto">
<div class="input-group input-number-group">
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement">-</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="input-number" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" step="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity']; ?>" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" />
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-increment">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
input-number-group {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.input-number-group input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.input-number-group input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

.input-number-group .input-group-button {
  line-height: calc(80px/2 - 5px);
}

.input-number-group .input-number {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-number-group .input-number,
.input-number-group .input-number-decrement,
.input-number-group .input-number-increment {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.input-number-group .input-number-decrement,
.input-number-group .input-number-increment {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.input-number-group .input-number-decrement {
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}

.input-number-group .input-number-increment {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
}
```

---

Final Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  
  jQuery('.quantity').each(function () {
    var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.input-number-increment'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.input-number-decrement'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = input.attr('max');

    btnUp.click(function () {
      var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
      if (oldValue >= max) {
        var newVal = oldValue;
      } else {
        var newVal = oldValue + 1;
      }
      spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
      spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
    });

    btnDown.click(function () {
      var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
      if (oldValue <= min) {
        var newVal = oldValue;
      } else {
        var newVal = oldValue - 1;
      }
      spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
      spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
    });

  });
});
</script>
```